# How to rearranges collapsed/pinned tabs in Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, tabs

I am using `Safari Version 15.0`, `macOS Big Sur Version 11.6`.

In `Safari`, on the left top side I can see the collapsed/pinned tabs, example:

[image]

In the previos Safari version, when I clicked one of the collapsed/pinned tabs, I was able to carry it into a new location. But now when I click them automatically Safari attempts to open them on a new window and I am unable to change their place.

How can I rearrenge collapsed/pinned tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading
from `macOS Big Sur` into [`macOS Monterey`](https://www.apple.com/macos/monterey/) solved the problem I was having.

Answer (score 1):

It now needs a longer click to trigger the rearrangement, just keep your finger pressed down a bit longer before trying to move pinned tabs :

[image: Safari pinned tab rearrangement]

### macOS 12.0.1 Monterey Safari 15.1 updates :

[image: Safari fixed tab rearrangement]

Comment: I believe that macOS Monterey fixes this. I have Safari 15.1 and the behavior is not as this image shows.

Comment: I am using inside macOS Big Sur and longer click does not help